# What is this called in C#?

Tags: c#, inline

```
Book x = new Book(){
              Author = "Rowling",
              Title = "Harry Potter",
              Genre = Genres.Fantasy
              };
```

I've tried googling for Inline declaration, but I guess thats not what it's officially called.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From what I've heard, it's called an object initializer.

Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 5):

This in itself appears to be illegal code.  It's very close to an object initializer but that would require the member being set to be paired with the value it was set to.  For example

```
Book x = new Book() { 
  Author = "Rowling",
  Title = "Harry Potter",
  Category = Geners.Fantasy };
```

**EDIT** OP corrected the question to now have the correct object initializer syntax.

Comment: Yep, this was what I meant, I was typing from my phone. Thanks!

Comment: So you should probably remove all the comment syou made? X-)

Comment: @astander was in the process of it.

Comment: i thing you forget to write comma after title value. are am right ?

Answer (score 1):

[Object Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have alook at 
[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)